# Kivy cannot be installed on Ubuntu 18.04 with Python 3.7.2

Tags: kivy

I have followed the instructions on official website of kivy.org to install kivy on my system. But when I type

from kivy.app import App

its showing "no module named 'kivy' ".

I am using ubuntu 18.04 with Python 3.7.2 installed.

1. Added ppa:

   $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy
2. Updated package list using your package manager:

   $ sudo apt-get update
3. Install Kivy:

   $ sudo apt-get install python3-kivy
4. Dependencies with legacy PyGame:

   sudo apt-get install -y \
   python-pip \
   build-essential \
   mercurial \
   git \
   python3 \
   python3-dev \
   ffmpeg \
   libsdl-image1.2-dev \
   libsdl-mixer1.2-dev \
   libsdl-ttf2.0-dev \
   libsmpeg-dev \
   libsdl1.2-dev \
   libportmidi-dev \
   libswscale-dev \
   libavformat-dev \
   libavcodec-dev \
   zlib1g-dev

Are there anything else that I need to do? Please help.

Comment: If you want to use Kivy stable version 1.10.1, install it in a virtual environment. For system installation, you have to use Kivy nightly builds (version 1.11.0.dev0), `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy-daily`

Comment: If I use the nightly builds then do I need to apply all the other commands as before? And will there be any need of virtual environment?